# Get DateTime from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a DateTime record in my table in a database and I write a query to get it from the database:

```
string command2 = "select Last_Modified from Company_Data where Company_Name='" + DescriptionEntryForm.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
SqlCommand search_company2 = new SqlCommand(command2, con_string.con);
SqlDataReader company_reader2 = search_company2.ExecuteReader();
dateform.Text = company_reader2.GetValue(0).ToString();
company_reader2.Close();
```

But the penultimate statement throw an exception saying "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present".

How can I solve it?

Comment: Do not concatenate queries like this, it is prone to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've executed the command, but haven't actually read from it.

```
company_reader2 = search_company2.ExecuteReader();
if (company_reader2 != null && company_reader2.HasRows) {
    company_reader2.Read();
    dateform.Text = company_reader2[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe `ExecuteReader` will ever return `null`. Personally I'd rather just use the return value of `Read()` instead of using `HasRows`, too. You've got to call it anyway, why not use it?

Comment: not need for if statement just 
company_reader2.Read();
dateform.Text = company_reader2[0].ToString();
thank you

Comment: @salamonti And what happens if your reader doesn't return any rows?

Comment: it is in try catch if it doesn't return any thing mean that company not in the database and get me just error

Answer (score 6):

Well, the *immediate* problem with your code is that you haven't called `company_reader2.Read()` to move the cursor onto the first row.

From the docs for [`SqlDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

> The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record.
>   Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data.

You should also note the return value of `Read()` which indicates whether or not you've read to the end of the record set.

Other problems:

- You should put `using` statements around the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`, otherwise if there's an exception you won't be closing the connection. You may be able to get away with disposing the command and letting the reader just disappear automatically - but I typically dispose of both just so I don't need to think too carefully.
- You're assuming that the format of date/time will be appropriate by just calling `ToString` with no format specifier.
- You should use a parameterised SQL query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Listen to this man - you really need to address *all* these points, particularly the parametrised queries and `using` commands.

Comment: just company_reader2.Read(); is missing to move the cursor thanks

Comment: @salamonti: Does your comment mean you're going to ignore the fact that you could easily leak database connections and leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks?